# Extracing version number from string using Bash script

Tags: bash

I am trying to get the version number from the following string:

```
mk5-VCC.6.26.exported.sqsh
```

The version number is the `6.26` number. So far I have used a sed command as follows:

```
echo "mk5-VCC.6.26.exported.sqsh" |
sed 's/^.*[^0-9]\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\).*$/\1/'
```

How do I remove the last dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Bash regex:

```
#!/bin/bash
s='mk5-VCC.6.26.exported.sqsh'
[[ $s =~ [0-9]+\.[0-9]+ ]]
echo "$BASH_REMATCH"
```

Using grep:

```
echo "$s" |grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
echo "mk5-VCC.6.26.exported.sqsh" | cut -d"." -f2,3
```

which prints:

```
6.26
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` you can use:

```
echo "mk5-VCC.6.26.exported.sqsh" | sed -e 's/^.*[.]\([0-9][.][0-9]*\).*$/\1/'
```

**output**

```
6.26
```

Answer (score 0):

With parameter expansion, assuming the number starts after the first `.` and there are two `.` after it:

```
$ var='mk5-VCC.6.26.exported.sqsh'
$ var="${var#*.}"
$ echo $var
6.26.exported.sqsh
$ var="${var%.*.*}"
$ echo $var
6.26
```